# auto pointer = NULL error

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, auto

I'm getting a compiling error:

```
error: unable to deduce ‘auto*’ from ‘0l’
```

When trying to compile my code:

```
random_device rd;
minstd_rand gen0(rd());
knuth_b gen1(rd());
ranlux24_base gen2(rd());

auto * generator = NULL; // error

switch(generatortmp) {
    case 0: generator = &gen0;
    more cases...
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: `auto generator = nullptr;`

Answer (score 5):

The type of the pointer cannot be deduced, as `NULL` carries no information regarding the type of the pointed element. **You need to explicitly specify the type**.

```
type* generator = nullptr;
```

Also, you should use [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) - never use `NULL` in modern C++.

---

> I'm trying to have this pointer be used to generate random numbers. I want it to be able to do something like (*generator)()

You could use a functional approach with a template:

```
template <typename TGenerator>
auto with_generator(TGenerator& generator)
{
    // use generator
}
```

```
switch(generatortmp) 
{
    case 0: with_generator(gen0); break;
    case 1: with_generator(gen1); break;
    // l...
}
```

Comment: You could have edited your other answer, but oh well :)

Comment: I can't specify the type as it depends on the case that is true.

Comment: @JackNewman: what are you trying to do? Sounds like you need a `template`

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I'm trying to have this pointer be used to generate random numbers. I want it to be able to do something like (*generator)(); which will generate the random number(and then do things with that number). I'm sorry I'm a beginner with c++ and I'm having trouble putting it into words.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `NULL` is usually defined as an integral constant equal to zero. It is C where `NULL` is defined like `( void * )0`. Thus if you want to use `auto` you have to write

```
auto * generator = ( void * )0;
```

Otherwise you should explicitly specify the type of pointer and use `nullptr`. For example

```
void * generator = nullptr;
```